# layout_toStartOf doesn't work fine when the element is gone

Tags: android-layout, visibility, android-relativelayout

Below is code that work fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_config_value"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_config_arrow"
        tools:text="122"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#44bb11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/iv_config_arrow"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I change visibility to invisible,it works fine too.
But if I change visibility to gone,it becomes strange.

[image]

[image]

Comment: how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I think android:layout_toStartOf cannot find **iv_config_arrow** because its gone.

whereas in **invisible**, the view is still there and can be reference by the TextView